# What is the correct way to make the different HTML elements accessible?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

Which one of the below methods is correct / better for making a link accessible?

```
<a href="http://example.com" aria-label="Title of post read more">Read More <i class="fas fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

OR

```
<a href="http://example.com"><span class="sr-only">Title of post</span> Read More <i class="fas fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

Which one of the methods is correct/ better for making a section accessible?

```
<section aria-label="Events"></section>
```

OR

```
<section aria-labelledby="hdng">
<h2 id="hdng">Events</h2>
</section>
```

OR

```
<section>
<h2 class="sr-only">Events</h2>
</section>
```

Comment: [ARIA](]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA) usage is highly recommended and more info is available at the linked site. But also think about using things like 'Skip to content' (if there's images/logos above the content. Also remember to use alt tags **where applicable** (if a pic is purely decorative, it [doesn't necessarily need one](https://webaim.org/techniques/alttext/) - read more about where to use these. Consider the [contrast](https://contrastchecker.com/) of your colours, and your [font size](https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/low-vision-a11y-tf/wiki/Text_Size)

Comment: By 'correct/better' I'm assuming you mean 'more compliant with ARIA and WCAG'?

Comment: @TylerH, basically we use ARIA for people with disabilities. So I wanted to know which method is better suitable to screen readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to expand upon the great answer by @thenomadicmann here is a bit of advice on the subject and **why** things are suggested in WCAG / general accessibility guidance.

### How should I include screen-reader friendly text in a link?

In the two examples you give (one using visually hidden text and one using an `aria-label`) you should use the visually hidden text.

There is one good reason for this, compatibilty.

[14 browser / screen reader combinations have problems with `aria-label` on links](https://www.powermapper.com/tests/screen-readers/labelling/a-aria-label/) (although support is very good)

However 100% of browser / screen reader combinations will read visually hidden text.

For this reason you should use

`<a href="http://example.com"><span class="sr-only">Title of post</span> Read More <i class="fas fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>`

#### Side note on icons

Consider replacing your font-awesome icons with inline SVGs. They are more accessibility friendly as they won't disappear if somebody overrides your site fonts (e.g. someone with dyslexia who prefers a certain font as it is easier for them to read). Plus font awesome is some 150kb of CSS and an inline SVG is about 1kb so it makes the site faster too if you only have a few icons!

### How to make a section accessible

By standards the following is the correct method

```
<section>
    <h2>section title example<h2>
</section>
```

However for maximum comparability you should use `aria-label` and [`role="region"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/Region_role).

```
<section aria-label="section title example" role="region">
    <h2>section title example<h2>
</section>
```

There are two points here.

1. `aria-label` support is nearly 100% (as discussed previously) whereas [`aria-labelledby` support is not as good](https://www.powermapper.com/tests/screen-readers/labelling/)
2. Around [2% of all screen reader users are still stuck on IE6-8](https://webaim.org/projects/screenreadersurvey8/#browsers). As such adding `role="region"` gives (almost) the same semantic meaning to those screen reader users.

#### Side Note(s) on regions and headings

1 - The `aria-label` will result in some duplicate announcements in some screen readers. However this is still preferable as a user may prefer to navigate by regions and as such announcing the region names is useful.

2 - In your comments you wondered why to use a `sr-only` heading vs a label.

I partially covered this in the previous point (`aria-label` is slightly less reliable than visually hidden text) but there is another reason.

While some screen reader users navigate by regions, others prefer to navigate a page by headings (i.e. in NVDA you press <kbd>NVDA key</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> to loop through all level 2 headings.).

This is why headings are important, in fact they are more important than correct use of `<section>` elements as this is how the majority of screen reader users will explore your page.

Answer (score 2):

For the link, [it should make sense out of context](https://webaim.org/techniques/hypertext/#link_to_link) so I'd use a `sr-only` class around helpful screen-reader specific text.

```
<a href="http://example.com"><span class="sr-only">Title of post</span> Read More <i class="fas fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

Regarding the section, [a major heading tag at the very beginning](https://usability.yale.edu/web-accessibility/articles/headings) will do the job well. If you want both screen-reader and regular users to see the heading, use a heading tag with an `aria-labelledby` attribute. If you only want screenreader users to see the heading, use the `sr-only` class again. Typically, you'd want all users to see a section heading though, so everyone can recognize the beginning of a new group of content.

```
<section aria-labelledby="hdng">
  <h2 id="hdng">Events</h2>
</section>
```

Comment: what in case if we have a section with no heading?

Comment: @user3284127 as I stated above, a section should always have a heading if you want to follow best practices. As I wrote above, if you only want screenreader users to see the heading, use the sr-only class again.

Comment: yes I get what you are saying. But what is wrong with using aria-label instead of heading with sr-only class for a section which does not have a heading to be displayed on the front end?